# EF7 Incorrect configuration of the DBContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to figure out if my DBContext is set right. The Web Application I am trying to do is using ASP.NET 5, MVC6 and EF7.

It is connected to a DB that contains 3 tables (Comment, Review, Film). This is my model

> WebDbModel.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebExample.Models
{
    public partial class Comment : IdentityUser
    {
        public string CommentId { get; set; }
        public string ReviewId { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Review : IdentityUser
    {
        public string ReviewId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Creator { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Film : IdentityUser
    {
        public string ReviewId { get; set; }
        public string FilmID { get; set; }
        public string CommentId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CommentCount { get; set; }
        public string FilmName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual Review Review { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then, I have a class named

> RegistrationDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace WebExample.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class RegistrationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        // Registration of the DB tables we are mapping.
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Film> Films { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am wondering from here what is the use of **public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser** 
I am not sure if I should leave it there... If I remove it, then in my Startup.cs, the following code will complain...

```
// Add Identity services to the services container.
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RegistrationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

So I don't know to what replace it given the fact I have **Comment**, **Review** and **Film** models...

So my question is... I guess I can delete the ApplicationUser class (auto generated when I created my solution) since this is not part of my model at all but... what should I put instead?

Not too sure if my question is right though, so apologies in advance! This seemed to be changed a lot compared to MVC5, EF6 and I couldn't fine too much documentation around **IdentityDbContext**

Also... am I missing something else in the **RegistrationDbContext.cs** class? The only extra thing I added was the registration of the tables... the rest came in the class by default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly, `IdentityUser` is the representation of a logged-in user to your site, and is by default represented by the `AspNetUsers` table in the database, and stores all the usual stuff like email address, password, etc.

The provided `ApplicationUser` subclass is there in case you want to extend that in any way. Say for example you want to store the date of birth of your users:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

That will tack on a `DateOfBirth` column to the `AspNetUsers` table.

In your case, if you don't want to extend the default user table in any way, you can just delete the `ApplicationUser` class and replace all references to it in your code to `IdentityUser`. For example:

```
// Add Identity services to the services container.
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RegistrationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Secondly, your models should not be inheriting from `IdentityUser`. That will just add all the fields from the `AspNetUsers` table to every model, which doesn't make sense, so remove `: IdentityUser` from your models.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand the logic much more now! Yeah, you were right, I don't need the ApplicationUser class so I removed it and referenced IdentityUser :)

Comment: BTW. If I have another question that is not related to this, I should open a new one, right?

Comment: @user3587624 Yes, that's right. That way you have the best chance of getting the right answer :)