# Linq on EF7 doesnt work with Joins and Dates?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am having some troubles running a query from a Controller on my ASP.NET MVC6 EF7 web app...

The Model and DbContext are in this previous ask: [EF7 Incorrect configuration of the DBContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171327/ef7-incorrect-configuration-of-the-dbcontext)

The problem appears when I try to run the following Linq query which contains a couple of joins and tries to get some entries from a Database for a particular date...

```
public IActionResult GetEntries(int year, int month, int day)
{
    //_context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(180);
    string dateTest = new DateTime(year, month, day).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    var results = (from c in _context.Comments
                   join r in _context.Reviews on c.ReviewId equals r.ReviewId
                   join f in _context.Films on c.ReviewId equals f.ReviewId 
                   where c.Author.Equals("AuthorTest")
                   && (c.Created.CompareTo(new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0)) >= 0) && (c.Created.CompareTo(new DateTime(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59)) < 0)
                   && !r.Status.Contains("Enabled")
                   select new 
                   {
                       ReviewId = c.ReviewId,
                       ReviewStatus = r.Status,
                       Author = c.Author
                   });
    var results2 = results.ToList();
    return View(results2);
}
```

The Exception that I get is...

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed
>   prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The funny thing is.... if I run the EXACT same query without the following line, then it works perfectly

```
&& (c.Created.CompareTo(new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0)) >= 0) && (c.Created.CompareTo(new DateTime(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59)) < 0)
```

So... the timeout exception thing doesn't make too much sense to me because once I remove the AND condition, it returns thousand of entries.

Also, if I plug that same query on a ASP.NET MVC5 EF6, the query works like a charm with the AND condition...

What am I missing here?

Finally, another thing that I tried was to create a single Linq query with no join and with the date condition and it works also perfectly...

```
public IActionResult GetEntries(int year, int month, int day)
{
    //_context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(180);
    string dateTest = new DateTime(year, month, day).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    var results = (from c in _context.Comments
                   where c.Author.Equals("AuthorTest")
                   && (c.Created.CompareTo(new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0)) >= 0) && (c.Created.CompareTo(new DateTime(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59)) < 0)
                   select new 
                   {
                       ReviewId = c.ReviewId,
                       Author = c.Author
                   });
    var results2 = results.ToList();
    return View(results2);
}
```

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because your Linq to Entities provider doesn't know how to translate the `CompareTo` method to SQL. Try creating the dates you want to compare outside of your query and later try to compare them in your query as I show below:

```
var d1=new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
var d2=new DateTime(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59);
var results = (from c in _context.Comments
               join r in _context.Reviews on c.ReviewId equals r.ReviewId
               join f in _context.Films on c.ReviewId equals f.ReviewId 
               where c.Author.Equals("AuthorTest")
               && c.Created >= d1 && c.Created<d2)
               && !r.Status.Contains("Enabled")
               select new 
               {
                   ReviewId = c.ReviewId,
                   ReviewStatus = r.Status,
                   Author = c.Author
               });
```

Comment: It worked! Man... I've been blocked with this stuff and tried several things but didn't think that that solution would work! Thanks a lot! Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, as a suggestion to the future try to use operators instead method calls inside your queries. As you can see, EF supports `Equals` and `Contains`, but there is a number very limited of methods that are supported.